# Add caching to mvc project in data layer (class library )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, architecture

i have an asp.net mvc based website, consist of three layers:

1. presentation layer (mvc website)
2. Domain layer (class library )
3. Data layer (class library)

and here is my code

**presentation layer:**

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int categoryId = 1)
    {
        var products = service.GetProductsByCategory(categoryId);
        return View(products );
    }
```

**Domain Layer:**

```
public List<MyProduct> GetProductsByCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        /* some code here */
        return myProductDao.GetProductsByCategory(categoryId);
    }
```

**Data Layer:**

```
public List<MyProduct> GetProductsByCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        /* check if data available in cache to avoid pulling database */
        using (var context = new myDbEntities())
        {
            var myproducts = context.ProductEntities.Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId);
            return Mapper.Map<List<ProductEntity>, List<Product>>(products);
        }
    }
```

We supposed that product table change only one time a day, and i want add a caching layer to avoid pulling database for a specific time.

**problem:**
i'm usually using HttpContext.Cache.Insert() in controller for caching, but now i'm planning to add caching to Data layer which it is a class library and there is no HttpContext. how usually caching done in datalayer

Comment: If needd, you can add a reference to the assembly which has HttpContext, in your data layer. but IMHO, I would personally do not add caching to the data layer. I would keep the data layer as it is so it always pull data from db. I will keep the caching layer inbetween the controllers and data access layer (may be a business layer)

Comment: @Shyju dose add a reference to the assembly which has HttpContext, the correct way to do that?

Comment: Oh man don't  add the reference, just create an interface and pass it down as a dependency..  posting answer.

Comment: Yea. That sounds the right way of doing it. You can create an implementation using redis/memory cache etc as needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this.  What I would do is abstract away the *how* to cache with an interface and inject however you want to cache into the data layer (including using HttpContext.Cache.Insert).

MyProject.Cache

```
public ICache
{
  void Insert (string key, object value)
}
```

MyProject.Web

```
internal WebCache : ICache
{
  public void Insert(string key, object value)
  {
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert(key, value);  
  }
}

public Controller
{
  private service = new service(new WebCache);
}
```

MyProject.Domain

```
public Service
{
  private readonly ICache _cache;
  private readonly MyProductDao _myProductDao;
  public Service(ICache cache;)
  {
    _cache = cache;
    _myProductDao = new MyProductDao(_cache);
  }

  public List<MyProduct> GetProductsByCategory(int categoryId)
  {
      /* some code here */
      return _myProductDao.GetProductsByCategory(categoryId);
  }
}
```

MyProject.Data (if you just want to cache in the data layer)

```
public MyProductDao
{
  private readonly ICache _cache;
  public MyProductDao(ICache cache)
  {
    _cache = cache;
  }

  public List<MyProduct> GetProductsByCategory(int categoryId)
  {
    /* check if data available in cache to avoid pulling database */
    _cache.DoWhatever()....

    using (var context = new myDbEntities())
    {
        var myproducts = context.ProductEntities.Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId);
        return Mapper.Map<List<ProductEntity>, List<Product>>(products);
    }
  }
```

Extend `ICache` as needed and implement it on your `internal WebCache`.

Answer (score 0):

> how usually caching done in datalayer

I don't think it *should* be done in the data layer.

Adding caching to the data layer seems to me like a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle. Your data layer should only be responsible for *one thing* - getting data from the persistent store (i.e. the database).

At some place in your code, you will need to do this workflow (or some variant of it):

1. Check the cache for item X.
2. If it is found, get the item from the cache.
3. If it is not found, get the item from the persistent store.
4. Return the item.

In my opinion, a component that is separate from the data layer should do this workflow.

Look at it this way: once you put a cache in front of your database persistence layer, you're not just getting data from the DB any more. You're getting data from this new component, and the component decides where to get the record from (cache vs. DB).